# Is it better when defining a new task rather than calling await directly?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In this example: `await delay(1000);` x5 takes 5 seconds to complete while `await Promise.all(...)` just needs 1 seconds.

```js
(async () => {
  let $log = console.log;
  let delay = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));

  $log(new Date().toString());

  await delay(1000);
  await delay(1000);
  await delay(1000);
  await delay(1000);
  await delay(1000);
  
  $log(new Date().toString());
  
  await Promise.all([delay(1000), delay(1000), delay(1000), delay(1000), delay(1000)]);
  
  $log(new Date().toString());
})();
```

My question is: For asynchronous method/function, is it better if we create a new task *(I'm not sure it's a real task or not)* before calling `await`?

And when to use `await` to wait an asynchronous method/function directly?

Comment: There are no tasks - asynchronous things simply return when the I/O (or sleep) operation has completed. Broadly speaking, I would say that if you are ready to process some data, you should do so. In your first configuration, it is as though one task depends on the results of the previous operation. In the latter configuration, there is no dependency between the tasks. Which is "better" to use depends on your use cases of the data returned by the previous task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) runs the promises in parallel and resolves when all have resolved. This is why `await Promise.all(...)` takes one second.

Which is "better" is a question of what you need to accomplish. If a later promise depends on the result of a previous one, you should execute them serially like this:

```
const result1 = await getPromise1();
const result2 = await getPromise2(result1);
```

Of course, you can wrap this all in its own promise to not block in the caller.

There's another detail which is that the `Promise.all` promise will reject if one of the promises rejects. You may not want this behavior; in other words, if an individual promise rejects, you may simply want to keep going. `Promise.all` will not work for that situation, but you could use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead.

Comment: should add Promise.allSettled as an alternative.  also await already implies that the function is wrapped in a Promise (an async function), so it does not block the caller by default.

Comment: Good tip, added a bit about allSettled. Also, my point about blocking in the caller still applies...while the enclosing function will be async and not block when called, within that function you may want to serially execute promises without blocking. i.e. the difference between `console.log('1'); await getPromise(); console.log('2');` and `console.log('1'); getPromise(); console.log('2');`.

Answer (score 1):

I like `await` because I think it's more direct than asynchronous pattern. But you must know that synchronous code means a queue being there. Tasks are finished one by one. In JS, you'd better take more advantages of it's so-called `event-driven` mechanism. Tasks should be pushed into the events queue as more quickly as possible. But there is a precondition that there's no dependency between any 2 of them.